# Should I check iTunes Store subscription before App login or after?

Tags: ios, iphone, subscriptions

In a case with iOS app only available via subscription should the user first see app login (my backend auth) and then requested to pay for subscription via iTunes Store or vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subscription should be linked to the login, so during the registration process they are required to purchase the subscription. However, make it clear to the user that a subscription is required.

Answer (score 0):

During the login process . Ask to backend to manage this thing.